# Getting "Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client" in Cypress

Tags: mysql, cypress

I was trying to connect to Mysql DB from cypress, did the following steps for the same.

Step 1: Added MySQL library in cypress

Step 2: Added following code in plugins/index.js file (This I have got while searching in google)

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
function queryTestDb(query, config) {
  // creates a new mysql connection using credentials from cypress.json 
env's
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.env.db)
  // start connection to db
  connection.connect()
  // exec query + disconnect to db as a Promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
      if (error) reject(error)
      else {
        connection.end()
        // console.log(results)
        return resolve(results)
      }
    })
  })
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // Usage: cy.task('queryDb', query)
  on('task', {
    queryDb :query =>  {
      return queryTestDb(query, config)
    },
  })
}
```

Step 3: Added the following dependencies in cypress.json

```
"env" : {
      "db": {
        "host": "name",
        "user": "user",
        "password": "password"
      }
    }
```

Step 4: Added the following code in the spec.js file

```
it('Verify the retrieved data', () => {
    cy.task('queryDb','select * from soandso where soandso = value').then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.rows)
      })
  })
```

But while running the spec file getting the below error

```
cy.task('queryDb') failed with the following error: > ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: No. I have cross-checked again. There is only one module.exports =

Comment: spec file is in \cypress\integration\testcases\filename.spec.js
The plugin file is in C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\cypress\plugins\index.js (In error absolute path was showing, I added as relative path)

Comment: how are you running this using run or open ? there is a unexcaped string env's delete that

Comment: same with me see if you add to cypress/plugins/index itslef not in anyother plugin folder

Comment: Now I realized that I have added in support/index.js, not in plugins/index.js. Correct that and tried again. This time I got the following error.
cy.task('queryDb') failed with the following error:

> ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Answer (score 0):

can you check your dependency in the package.json?

It should have sth like below.

"dependencies": {
"mysql": "^2.18.1"
}

If you do not have this dependency, you need to run 'npm install mysql'